# SOA Suite 12c OSB routing service to HTTPS basic authentication secured service

Tags: https, basic-authentication, oracle12c, osb, soa-suite

I am using Oracle fusion middleware 12.2.1.3.0
I am trying to create basic proxy service to HTTPS basic authentication secured service.
Can anybody explain step by step how to setup business service?
I have tried all combination but all went wrong.

- Proxy service is plain with http transport. There is not authentication, security nor policy.
- Pipeline is plain too = only routing to business service.
- Business service transport protocol http (there are not other options allowed). URI = https://my.uri.com:443/ws/myService?wsdl

Http transport configuration = Authentication Basic, Service account = myAccount.sa (username/password)
No policies.
Business Service Testing gives me "The invocation resulted in an error: Forbidden."

When I supply username/password into testing window it gives me "Error authenticating the transport username/password: [Security:090938]Authentication failure: The specified user failed to log in.   javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090302]Authentication Failed: User specified user denied"

When I try add oracle/http_basic_auth_over_ssl_client_policy I get "Conflicts found during publish.
[OSB-387194]OWSM Policy 'oracle/http_basic_auth_over_ssl_client_policy' is not allowed since transport authentication is set to 'basic'. If you are trying to attach an HTTP Token Policy make sure that the authentication on transport configuration is set to 'None'. You can either set the authentication mechanism directly on the transport configuration page or attach OWSM HTTP Token Policy."

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not add security to BS.
In the Business Configuration tab,put the authentication to 'None' instead of Basic. You should attach security only to Proxy Service and not Business Service.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have been successful with my configuration. Only thing I have done was recreate pipeline.